# Mac /usr/local and homebrew

Tags: macos, local, osx-lion, homebrew

Anyone know what a "virgin" `/usr/local` folder would look like on a brand new Mac? I *should* know, as I just got one, but I used **Apple's Migration Assistant** (which doesn't give you *any* details about what it's about to do) to migrate my Mail, Apps & things. Well, apparently leaving that curious "Other Files & Folder" setting checked means all my compiled tools and configuration files have come across as well (RMagick, Git, Mongoid, RVM, etc).

Problem is I was looking forward to taking this opportunity (new machine) to switch to **HomeBrew** as a package manager instead of doing the `config/make/install` dance on my own every time I want to update something. *Besides, the versions that came over from older machine were compiled for different hardware and won't even work on this machine.*

So, can I just dump or move everything in `/usr/local` and get going with homebrew? Any advice? Caveats? I think I also have some things in `/opt/` too…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Lion, /usr/local does not exist by default (although /usr/local/bin is in the default $PATH -- if you build it, they will come).

Comment: great! thank you! I will clean it out & start anew!